# About a theorem that appears in Mrówka's article.

Tags: general-topology

I was reading and [article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889557) of S. Mrówka and I found a theorem that sounds good but, unfortunately, I can't figure out the proof. The theorem is 1.3 in the article:

> 1.3 Theorem (The formal theorem) If $h$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ into $Y$, then there exist a superspace $X^{*}$ (i.e., an space that contains $X$ as a subspace) of $X$ which is homeomorphic to $Y$ by a homeomorphism $h^{*}$ wich is an extension of $h$.

I don't know how to prove it and, moreover, I can't find the proof in another articles. In fact, in the article doesn't exist a reference about such theorem.

I though in take $h$ as the identity function because, roughly speaking, we can consider $X$ as a subspace of $Y$ and trivially $h$ extends to $h^{*}=\text{id}:Y\to Y$ and $h^{*}$ is an homeomorphism. I know that this isn't the general case, but, in the practice, an extension $T$ of a space $X$ can always viewed such that $X\subseteq T$. Am I wrong? How can I take the general case? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $h$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ into $Y$. Let

$$X^*=X\cup\big(\{X\}\times(Y\setminus h[X])\big)\,,$$

and define

$$h^*:X^*\to Y:z\mapsto\begin{cases}
h(z),&\text{if }z\in X\\
z,&\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$

clearly $h^*$ is a bijection, and $h^*\upharpoonright X=h$. We define the topology $\tau$ on $X^*$ so as to make $h^*$ a homeomorphism:

$$\tau=\left\{(h^*)^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in }Y\right\}\,.$$

It only remains to check that the topology that $X$ inherits from $\tau$ is its original topology, which is straightforward.